# Requests (последняя строка) не видит cс, подскажите что исправить что бы cc был виден

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests


class Requests:
    def init(self, const_currency):
        self.const_currency = const_currency
        self.currency = input("• ").lower().strip()
        try:
            self.value = float(input("• "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Only numerical values")
        self.r = requests.get(f"http://www.floatrates.com/daily/{self.const_currency}.json").json()
        if self.const_currency == "usd":
            self.course = {"usd": 1, "eur": self.r["eur"]["rate"]}
        elif self.const_currency == "eur":
            self.course = {"usd": self.r["usd"]["rate"], "eur": 1}
        else:
            try:
                self.course = {"usd": self.r["usd"]["rate"], "eur": self.r["eur"]["rate"]}
            except KeyError:
                pass
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def cache_check(self):
        print("Checking the cache...")
        if self.currency in self.course.keys():
            self.cache_read()
        else:
            self.cache_write()

    def cache_write(self):
        try:
            while True:
                print(f"""Sorry, but it is not in the cache!
You received {round(self.r[self.currency]["rate"] * self.value, 2)} {"".join(self.currency).upper()}.
""")
                self.course.update({self.currency: self.r[self.currency]["rate"]})
                break
        except AttributeError:
            print("Incorrect attribute")
        except KeyError:
            print("Incorrect attribute")

    def cache_read(self):
        print(f"""It is in the cache!
You received {round(self.course[self.currency] * self.value, 2)} {"".join(self.currency).upper()}.\n""")

    def main(self):
        self.cache_check()
        while True:
            self.currency = input("• ").lower().strip()
            try:
                self.value = float(input("• "))
                self.cache_check()
            except ValueError:
                print("Only numerical values")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cc = input("• ").lower().strip()
    Requests(cc).main()
```

Comment: В заголовке что-то пропущено. Слишком много кода не относящего к делу - нужно показывать минимально воспроизводимый код. Не приведено сообщение об ошибке, которую получаете.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\untitled2\currency-exchange\beta.py", line 61, in <module>
    Requests(cc).main()
TypeError: Requests() takes no arguments это то что выбивает

Comment: Requests.main(cc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке говорит не о том что "не видит сс", а о том, что в `Requests` конструктор без параметров, а вы передаете параметр. Проблема в том, что вы неправильно объявили конструктор в `Requests`.

`def init(self, const_currency)` замените на `def __init__(self, const_currency)`